Vercel Error not seen in local prod build - but app will nnot build
I am trying to deploy my app to Vercel and running into issues. For example, I am getting an unexpected token error coming from the layout.tsx file:
I ran prod build locally and it was fine no issues and confirming I have the same version of node in my project as Vercel is using. Please help I have no idea why this is an error.
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ","
5 | export default function RootLayout({
6 |   children,

7 | } :{
|   ^
8 |   children: React.ReactNode,
9 | }) {
10 |   return (

